# Custom rails environment, devise complains about secret key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, environment

I have created a new environment `dev_fast_assets` where I do many optimizations (precompiling assets...) so as to improve the responsiveness of the website on slow laptops (because when serving assets takes 20sec+, you end up drinking too much coffee)

So I have basically created a new file in `/config/environments`, (almost a copy-paste from development.rb), I have added in `mongoid.yml`, `ldap.yml`, and I believe that's all there is to do.

But when I run `rails s -e dev_fast_assets`, I get a

```
C:/Dev/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:480:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. 
Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
config.secret_key = 'yyyy
```

Now I happen to already have a `config.secret_key = 'xxxx'` (different from `yyyy`) in my `config.initializers/devise.rb`, and so far I've never had problems with deployment in production using capistrano.

What am I missing ? Basically I want my `dev_fast_assets` environment to behave almost exactly like the `development` one, except for maybe one line of two that changes...

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to 'active_reload' gem. Try to remove it from your Gemfile  and then try again. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2641

Comment: I have checked my Gemfile and my Gemfile.lock, no sign of such a gem :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with Rails 4.1.2, Devise 3.2.4 and Devise-Invitable 1.3.5:

```
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

  config.secret_key = '[128 hexadecimal characters]'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
```

What I did:

1. Added the key to the file as it requested (replacing `config/initializers/devise.rb:7`, which was commented out with a different key)
2. Ran `rails g devise:install`. At the time, I had an environment variable set with `RAILS_ENV=demo`, but I don't know if that was required.

It seemed to work.